# Programmatically change text config files in Linux with minimal effort

Tags: configuration-files

I am looking for a tool that would ease the modification of text configuration files for tasks like:

- Set `ForwardAgent yes` on /etc/ssh/ssh_config
- Append `HGUSER` to `AcceptEnv` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config (that's more complex as it does accept several params, if yours is not alread there it should add it)

Most important:

- running it several times should have no side effects.
- if something looks weird, it should complain (for example if you find the same line several times in a file, or if the expected syntax does not match).

Is there any linux tool that can easily be used to automate things like this?

The whole point is to be able to write these config patches somewhere so you can deploy them on several machines or on a new machine when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly do this with bash scripting.  Here is a great tutorial.

http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial

to change a line in a file you could do something like:
check the file exists
grep for the value you want to change - error if it appears multiple times or something
use sed to change that line

to append something to a file
check if file exists
grep to ensure it hasn't been appended to already
echo whatever >> file - the double greater than appends to a file

with each of these I would make a backup copy of the file first, just in case something goes wrong

Comment: That was my first though, still I'm looking for a way of making easy to do `change_conf('/path/file','key','value')`. Probably I will end-up writing these utility functions myself in bash. (update, append).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the [Unified Configuration Interface (UCI)](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci) used in Embedded Linux systems. If you have the flexibility to adapt the UCI format for your config files, this is pretty similar to what you are looking for.